# Should I be able to access network locations in MVC3 without impersonation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

This sort of question is a first for me, because I'm wondering if something that IS working SHOULD be working.

We have:

**Server 1** -  Win2K3 file server, which is also our domain server.

**Server 2** -  Win2008 R2 server where our MVC3 site is deployed, which is also joined to the domain.

I have code on server 2 that uses .NET file system (IO) classes to access server 1 using UNC paths that point to network shared directories, such as `\\10.1.1.1\FileDirectory\`.

This code works just fine, and we're not using impersonation or delegation.  I'm wondering if this SHOULD work, or if it points to bad network permissions setup on server 1.  I thought the MVC3 site ran as a local server system account of some sort that wouldn't have any domain access, which is why I'm confused.

Here are 2 screen shots of the permissions for the shared directory on server 1.

Share Perms

[image]

NTFS Perms

[image]

---

Thanks for any input.  Let me know if I can clarify further or provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear the the user your site runs as (App Pool Identity?) counts as an 'Authenticated User' from the perspective of the server with the share.

http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/user-management-and-profiles/understanding-the-authenticated-users-group

Comment: I've researched, and can't find anything indicating that an app pool identity would be somehow tied to an active directory account or group.  I'm absolutely NOT a server admin - am I missing the obvious?

Comment: An 'Authenticated User' doesn't have to be a AD account per the article I linked. Try removing that one and see if it stops the access. If not, I'd remove the others one by one to see which grants the access.